# NestJs with TypeORM migrations fail

Tags: postgresql, nestjs, typeorm, nestjs-config

I use this boilerplate app to learn NestJs [GITHUB LINK](https://github.com/brocoders/nestjs-boilerplate.git). The template is amazing but there was one thing that I can't fix migrations. When I try to add a new entity or use an existing one with `npm run migrate:create Init` migration was successful

> Migration D:/src/database/migrations/1657796180301-init.ts

has been generated successfully.
but without any updating on the migration file or database. Only If I use synchronize: true and start the app the database was updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to run `migration:generate` to generate new migrate file.

Answer (score 0):

You have to run `migration:run` to apply migrations. This process is not done automatically because some migrations will cause you to loose data (dropping a column for example), so this gives you a chance to validate migration file before applying it.

Comment: Yes but the problem is that with npm run migrate:create Init does not apply or create any table from entities. The migrations files are empty. Just try it, before that delete the migrations folder.